# Understanding period of a sine wave in physics

Tags: waves

For a periodic function to be represented as a Fourier series, it must have a period of $2\pi$. This seems to bother me. The period is the length in time for a complete cycle for a sinusoid. However, if a function has a period of $2\pi$, does that mean it takes $2\pi$ seconds for a complete cycle?

Comment: You can take a Fourier series over a function with any period. $2\pi$ is the canonical choice, but not by any means the only one.

Comment: Physically speaking though, @probably_someone , does a period of $2\pi$ imply $2\pi$ seconds? Or some length in physical time at all? It would seem very unnaturally specific.

Comment: It doesn't imply anything. The only reason the Fourier transform is typically first introduced using a period of $2\pi$ is because the basis functions are easiest to write down that way. In any application of the Fourier transform, factors of the function's period will show up in three places: as a constant in front, in the limits of integration, and modifying the period of the basis functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, the $2\pi$ period (no dimension or unit) is mathematically the period of a sinusoid on the real numbers axis. If you want a sinusoid to represent a period $T$ in time, you have to use the argument $$\frac {2\pi t}{T}$$ where $T$ is the period in s, and $t$ is the time in s.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the answer, it is just a matter of understanding who-is-who. Stating that a function is periodic with period $2\pi$ means that if *its argument* is shifted by $2\pi$, than the function acquires the same value. As you said, it is the case of the sine function , for example $$
\sin(x) = \sin(x+2\pi) = \sin(x+2k\pi) \quad \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots\}$. When you talk about time in Fourer series, you handle objects like this
$$
\sin(\omega t)
$$
where $\omega=2\pi/T$ and $T$ is the period. The argument is their product, not the time alone, and it is in this form because it must be an angle, a dimensionless variable. And here the snag: being the sine function periodic with period $2\pi$, then
$$
\sin(\omega t) = \sin(\omega t+2\pi) =\sin(\omega(t+T))
$$
so you can say that *$T$ is the period* in the sense that each $T$ seconds the function assumes the same value, the function being periodic of $2\pi$ in its argument.

Answer (score 0):

A periodic function only fulfills the following minimum condition: $f(z+M)=f(z)$. 
$M$ is in this case the period. I chose the letter $M$ in order to avoid any similarities with time or position, although in most cases $z$ will represent position or time.

$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \exp\left( \frac{2\pi i n z}{M}\right) $

$c_n$ can be computed in the following way ($n$ runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$)

$c_n =\frac{1}{M} \int_{0}^{M} f(z) \exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i n z}{M}\right)dz $

It can be checked out that the expression above fulfills $f(z+M)=f(z)$

So it neither needs to be function of time nor of sinusoidal form.  The latter is only a special case. For instance the function can have periodical rectangular or triangular form and the $M$ can take on any positive value including $2\pi$. 
If this representation looks to abstract, the exponential can be decomposed according to $ exp(i x) = cos (x) + i sin( x)$. For the expression above $x = \frac{2\pi nz}{M}$. 
If the coefficients $c_n$ are chosen appropiately  (all $c_n=0$ except $c_1 =-\frac{i}{2}$ and $c_{-1} =\frac{i}{2}$ ) a pure sinus function $f(z) = \sin(2\pi \frac{z}{M})$ can be obtained. This one of course fulfills $f(z+M)=f(z)$.